# rails aws-s3 delete file throws AWS::S3::PermanentRedirect error - EU bucket problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I'm building a rails3 app on heroku, and I'm using aws-s3 gem to manipulate files stored in an Amazon S3 eu bucket.

When I try to perform a **AWS::S3::S3Object.delete filename, 'mybucketname'** command, I get the following error:

> AWS::S3::PermanentRedirect (The bucket you are attempting to access
>   must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future
>   requests to this endpoint.):

I have added the following to my ***application.rb*** file:

> ```
>  AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(  
>    :access_key_id     => "myAccessKey",  
>    :secret_access_key => "mySecretAccessKey" 
>  )
> ```

and the following code to my controller:

> > def destroy
> >         song = tape.songs.find(params[:id])
> >
> > ```
> > AWS::S3::S3Object.delete song.filename, 'mybucket'
> >
> > song.destroy
> >
> >
> > respond_to do |format|  
> >     format.js   { render :nothing => true } 
> >   end     end
> > ```

I found a proposed solution somewhere to add **AWS_CALLING_FORMAT: SUBDOMAIN** to my **amazon_s3.yml** file, as supposedly, aws-s3 should handle differently eu buckets than us.
However, this did not work, same error is received.

Could you please provide any assistance?
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is you need to type SUBDOMAIN as uppercase string in config, try this out

Comment: it works with s3syn gem, but has a problem with "aws-s3" gem. you can take a look at the [solution](https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3/issues/4) on Github Issues for this project

Comment: Thanks mikhailov for your replies. Indeed I found the answer on Github, seems that entering 'AWS::S3::DEFAULT_HOST.replace "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"' to your environment.rb file does the trick!

Comment: AWS::S3::DEFAULT_HOST.replace "s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com" - works for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify custom endpoint at connection initialization point:

```
    AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
      :access_key_id     => 'myAccessKey',
      :secret_access_key => 'mySecretAccessKey',
      :server            => 's3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com'
    )
```

you can find actual endpoint through the AWS console:

[image]

full list of valid options - here https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3/blob/master/lib/aws/s3/connection.rb#L252

```
VALID_OPTIONS = [:access_key_id, :secret_access_key, :server, :port, :use_ssl, :persistent, :proxy].freeze
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to set the constant to the actual service link at initialization time.
in config/initializers/aws_s3.rb

```
  AWS::S3::DEFAULT_HOST = "s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com"
  AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
      :access_key_id     => 'access_key_id',
      :secret_access_key => 'secret_access_key'
  )
```