# How to delete files in amazon S3 from ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I have made a ruby on rails application with amw S3.

I can upload the photo, but I try to delete the photo, even though the photo reference is deleted in database, the photo is still in S3.

How do I actually delete files from S3?

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't correctly specified. If you could provide more information, it would be great. But here are some options how to handle files on Amazon S3.

According to [this documentation](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/) you can use [method **delete**](https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3/blob/master/lib/aws/s3/object.rb#L220)(see the implementation) from the [Ruby Library for Amazon's Simple
Storage Service's (S3) REST API.](https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3)

So the should look like this:

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.delete('goodbye.txt', 'my-new-bucket')
```

Very helpful could be also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717321/rails-aws-s3-delete-file-throws-awss3permanentredirect-error-eu-bucket-pro).

Anyway I highly recommend you to use [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) when uploading files to Amazon S3. Some helpful articles:

1. [Configure Carrierwave for Amazon S3 Storage and Heroku](https://gist.github.com/cblunt/1303386)
2. [RailsCast #383 Uploading to Amazon S3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3)